# How to fix my nonworking Python regex match?

Tags: python, regex

I want to grab the whole number out of this string `<some>some 344.3404.3 numbers<tag>`.

Using the Pythex emulator website this works with `[\d\.]*` (a digit or point repeated zero or more times).
In Python i get back the whole string:

Input:

```
import re
re.match(r'[\d\.]*', '<some>some 344.3404.3 numbers<tag>').string
```

Output:

```
'<some>some 344.3404.3 numbers<tag>'
```

What am i missing?

Running python 3.3.5, win7, 64bit.

Comment: please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171045/python-regular-expression-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `string` attribute of a regex match object contains the *input* string of the match, not the matched content.

If you want the (first) matching part, you need to change three things:

- use `re.search()` because `re.match()` will only find a match at the start of the string,
- access the `group()` method of the match object,
- use `+` instead of `*` or you'll get an empty (zero-length) match unless the match happens to be at the start of the string.

Therefore, use

```
>>> re.search(r'[\d.]+', '<some>some 344.3404.3 numbers<tag>').group()
'344.3404.3'
```

or

```
>>> re.findall(r'[\d.]+', '<some>some 344.3404.3 numbers more 234.432<tag>')
['344.3404.3', '234.432']
```

if you expect more than one match.

Comment: Quick question: why does `groups()` return an empty tuple here? According to the documentation it should contain all the matched subgroups.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ: There are no subgroups (group 0 doesn't count as a subgroup).

Comment: I see. Thanks for answering. I constructed a group using parentheses to confirm :p

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
re.search(r'[\d.]+', '<some>some 344.3404.3 numbers<tag>').group()
```

Notes: Your pattern didn't work because `[\d.]*` will match the empty string at the first position. This is why I have replaced the quantifier with `+` and changed the method from *match* to *search*.

There is no need to escape the dot inside a character class, since it is seen by default as a literal character.