# Parsing a string pattern - Python

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I have a string pattern (for a `xml` test reporter) in the following pattern:

```
'testsets.testcases.[testset].[testcase]-[date-stamp]'
```

For example:

```
a='testsets.testcases.test_different_blob_sizes.TestDifferentBlobSizes-20150430130436'
```

I know I always can parse the `testset` and `testcase` names by doing:

```
temp = a.split("-")[0]
current = temp.split(".")
testset = '.'.join(current[:-1]) + ".py"
testcase = current[-1]
```

However, I want to accomplish that using a more pythonic way, like `regex` or any other expression that I would do it in a single line. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Regular Expression example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171045/python-regular-expression-example)

Comment: What are `s` and its `name` that you suddenly begin to use?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi sorry will update the question

Comment: @JoelHinz I dont think they are possible duplicates ... I'm looking for a more general pattern than the one asked in that question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
testset, testcase = re.search('(.*)\.(.*)-.*', a).group(1, 2)
testset += '.py'
```

[`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) returns a [`MatchObject`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) on matches, and it has a [`group`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) method we can use to extract match groups for the regex ("()"s in the regex).

Comment: This an incorrect regex. Look at the OP where brackets indicated the desired groups in a certain string.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `groups` that are obtained from the regular expression searched groups:

```
data = re.search(r'.+\..+\.(.+)\.(.+)-(\d+)', string).groups()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly want to pull out the testset and testcase, i.e. "test_different_blob_sizes" and "TestDifferentBlobSizes", as in the first part of your question, you can just do:

```
testset, testcase = re.split('[.-]',s)[2:4]
```

For compact regexp-based code based on what you have, see Ziyao Wei's response.